# How many numbers we can create using $1,2,3,4$ when repetition is allowed?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many numbers we can create using $1,2,3,4$ when repetition is allowed?

Condition: The number must have at most 5 digits.

My Attempt :

5 Digit number of numbers: $4\times4\times4\times4\times4 =1024$

4 Digit number of numbers : $4\times4\times4\times4 =256$

3 Digit number of numbers : $4\times4\times4 =64$

2 Digit number of numbers : $4\times4 =16$

1 Digit number of numbers: $4 =4$

Am I missing something? The answer given is $3125$

Comment: Are zeros allowed?  $3125 = 5^5$.

Comment: Yes. u r correct. I don't think you are missing anything

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether you're looking for strings or numbers.  Take max 2 digits for example,

`1,2,3,4,11,12,13,14,21,22,23,24,31,32,33,34,41,42,43,44` -> 4+4^2 = 20 numbers

`__,_1,_2,_3,_4,1_,2_,3_,4_,11,12...`                     -> 5^2 = 25 strings, where `_` is to represent empty string.

Comment: Empty string can just be thought of as zeroes

Comment: you are over complicating the problem